# Prevent /wp-admin/ from redirecting to homepage?

Tags: wp-admin, url-rewriting, redirect, dashboard

I have copied a wordpress instance from production to my local.  After getting the public side of the site up - public homepage, pages, and blog posts -, I cannot access /wp-admin/ because that url always redirects to the / homepage.  I have tried:

- Updating the siteurl and home to "https://tk.local" (homepage and posts work fine)
- Implementing a local self-signed ssl cert (in case it was an https problem.)
- Switched to 2019 theme (theme works, but problem still persists)
- Setting debug constants in wp-config.php
- Removing debug constants in wp-config.php
- Moved the plugins directory aside, replaced with /plugins containing only index.php

Here is a curl of wp-admin:

```
curl -Ik https://tk.local/wp-admin/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.16.0
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 17:27:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
Location: https://tk.local/
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 17:27:39 GMT
Expires: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 18:27:39 GMT
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
ETag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-uri: /wp-admin/
```

Obviously on the production copy the wp-admin url works. Throughout it all, it 301 redirects from `https://tk.local/wp-admin to https://tk.local/`
How can I prevent it from redirecting?

Comment: Have you disabled all your plugins on `tk.local` and switched to a default theme? What does the `.htaccess` file look like on `tk.local`? When you say you tried *Updating the siteurl and home to "tk.local"*, did you set them to `tk.local` or `https://tk.local`?

Comment: @PatJ Yes.  I moved the plugins directory away and replaced it with a clean install version that just contains index.php, still redirects.  No .htaccess, I am using nginx without any redirections that list wp-admin.  Yes, the siteurl and home setting are set to https.

Comment: Does there happen to be an .htaccess file within the wp-admin folder?  Have you tried starting with a fresh copy of WordPress and copying in the wp-content folder from the production site?

Comment: @socki03 Your idea to replace the outer source code make it clear that since the source was identical to wordpress 5, it had to be my nginx config.  I wouldn't have thought of just wiping all the non wp-content source code temporarily, but it was helpful.  If you want to make it an answer, I'd look at giving that the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it ended up being some kind of adverse interaction in the nginx wordpress config that I had.  Something about not passing along the naked arguments:

```
        location / {
original line:               try_files $uri @php;
new line:        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

And the associated upstream was wrong.  Used the config suggested here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/
For a simpler wordpress nginx config and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try going into the local database and looking in the `options` table for the home and site url. Make sure these values correctly reference the local site URL.

Alternatively, in your local wp-config.php file you could try defining the home and site url constants like this:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Answer (score 1):

- Look into `.htaccess`, there might be set some specific urls/directories, which you might need to remove/change, like:

  RewriteBase /subdir/
- Also, in phpmyadmin, check `wp-options` first and second rows, there should be needed similarly modified site-url .
- If MultiSite, then change that in `wp-config` too.